# Can we directly load the data from ibm queue to oracle DB?

Tags: ibm-mq, oracle12c

Can we directly load the data from ibm queue to oracle  DB ?

I have googled and spend a lot of time but i could not get required information.
It will be helpfull if someone provide right direction.
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Hi Fresher, I don't have any experiance with it it but there seems to be something called Oracle Service Bus that can do this, here is a search of Stackoverflow for questions including tags for both products: [oracle-service-bus and ibm-mq or osb and ibm-mq](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle-service-bus%5D+and+%5Bibm-mq%5D+or+%5Bosb%5D+and+%5Bibm-mq%5D)

Comment: Thanks @JoshMc. I will check with that. I will update here once I found the required info.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do it directly, you will need something in between to read MQ messages and write the data into DB.